# List adapter display text vs. saved text

Tags: android

what I have now is a listView with 3 items in it: Audience, Choosing topics, and Interviewing strategies. I want to be able to save these items as strings to open url with associated item name in the path, but the problem comes when the path has a different item name than the one I have in the listview items; we have Audience, Choosing_topics, and Interviewing as their names. How would I go about dealing away with this conflict in name without changing the names of the url or the listViewItem? Should I refer to another string array to compare the value of the first string array to to retrieve the associated item in the new array? Here's what I have as of now:

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, GREATESTHITS));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
          String text = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
          ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(text);
     String str = DownloadText("http://www.jmu.edu/uwc/" + text + ".html"); 



static final String[] GREATESTHITS = new String[] {"Audience", "Choosing topics", "Interviewing Strategies"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the best way to deal with this is to use objects. You create a model for each of your strings on your `GREATESTHITS`. You can then add another property for the url or whatever extra you want.

After that is created, you create and `ArrayAdapter<YourTypeHere>` and on the `ListView` you can set the adapter you just created.

After that on the `ItemClickListener` you can use this:

```
YourTypeHere item = (YourTypeHere) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

there you have the object on the array, and you can access all the properties you've set for that object.

This seems a little bit overkill for only 3 items, but it is the right way to go.

On an easier approach you can set a `HashMap<String, String> urlNames`, add a hash with each text and it's relative url. After that, on the listener you can do

```
String text = (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
      ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(text);
String str = DownloadText("http://www.jmu.edu/uwc/" + urlNames.get(text) + ".html");
```